# ProgressDialog circle stops to spin when intensive calculations are in background

Tags: android, android-widget

I need advice about ProgressDialog , I show dialog like

```
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(
                    Dashboard.this,
                    "LOADING...",
                    "PLEASE WAIT", true, false);
```

and it shows, but it when in background is intensive calculation that circle stops to spin ( like it is blocked). I am running this code above inside onClick button. What to change to avoid this blocking or that is impossible ?

Comment: what r u doing when dialog is running?

Comment: Use AsyncTask to do your intensive calculations.

Comment: @Damir I'm having same issue, did you find any solution? In my case first time the dialog works perfectly, but when I use the same dialog second time with aonther message, then the circle stops spinning, though my app or activity not blocked/hanged.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your intensive calculation to another Thread, to not block UI thread

see another SO question for example how to use `AsyncTask` and `ProgressDialog` together

[progressDialog in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538370/492624)

Answer (score 1):

When you say your progress dialog does not spin, it actually means that your intensive calculation is blocking the main /UI thread

you should make use of an [`Asynctask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Also get a hang of [painless threading in android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

It will run in the background without causing hiccups in the UI thread...

Since android apps run on a single main (UI ) thread, you should avoid doing heavy tasks on the UI thread

An asynctask is basically an intelligent worker thread provided by the android system.. It contains helper methods wherein you can easily decide what you want to do

A progress dialog should be created in onPreExecute() and dismissed in onPostExecute()

**Do intensive task in doInBackgound()**

Here are some tutorials:

[easy to understand asynctask](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/)