# Android listview scroll to bottom to load more data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am creating an application in which i have a expandable list view which loads the data from sq lite. At first i have set the limit as 10 to the select query and when the list reaches the end i want to load another 10 data's from the sq lite to list view. I have used list-scrolling option to find the last item in the list view but it didn't works as expected can anyone tell me how i have to fetch the data's from sq lite and load those into the list view when the list reaches ends.

Query:

```
 ArrayList<Daybook> daybookDetails = new ArrayList<Daybook>();
    String selectquery = "SELECT date,IFNULL(SUM(amountin),0) as amountin,IFNULL(SUM(amountout),0) as amountout,daybookusertype FROM daybookdetails GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) DESC LIMIT " + s + "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Daybook daybookentries = new Daybook();
            daybookentries.setDate(cursor.getString(0));
            daybookentries.setCashin(cursor.getString(1));
            daybookentries.setCashout(cursor.getString(2));
            daybookDetails.add(daybookentries);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return daybookDetails;
```

Expandable Listview:

```
    daybooks = new ArrayList<Daybook>();
    daybooks = databaseHandler.getAlldaybookentriesdatewise(olimit);
    daybooklists = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();


    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < daybooks.size(); i++) {
        String date = daybooks.get(i).getDate();
        if (date != null) {
            String s = date;
            String[] spiliter = s.split("-");
            String year = spiliter[0];
            String month = spiliter[1];
            String dates = spiliter[2];
            if (month.startsWith("01")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Jan" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Feb" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Mar" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Apr" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "May" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Jun" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Jul" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Aug" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Sep" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Oct" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Nov" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
                disorderedlist = dates + "Dec" + year;
                disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            }
            listDataHeader.add(disorderedlist);
        }

        chid = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();
        daybooklists = databaseHandler.getAllDaywisedaybookdetails(date);
        for (int j = 0; j < daybooklists.size(); j++) {


            String name = daybooklists.get(j).getName();
            String desc = daybooklists.get(j).getDescription();
            String type = daybooklists.get(j).getType();
            String usertype = daybooklists.get(j).getUsertype();
            String amtin = daybooklists.get(j).getAmountin();
            String amtout = daybooklists.get(j).getAmountout();
            String extamt = daybooklists.get(j).getExtraamt();
            String mobno = daybooklists.get(j).getMobileno();
            String dates = daybooklists.get(j).getSdate();
            String time = daybooklists.get(j).getCtime();


            if (name != null) {
                chid.add(new Daybooklist(name, desc, type, usertype, amtin, amtout, extamt, mobno, dates, time));

            }

        }


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), chid);
    }
```

ListView scrolling:

```
 expListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            int btn_initPosY = fabaddnew.getScrollY();
            int li_initPosY = li_general.getScrollY();
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {

                listAdapter.isScrolling(true);

                fabaddnew.animate().cancel();
                fabaddnew.animate().translationYBy(150);

            } else {

                listAdapter.isScrolling(false);
                fabaddnew.animate().cancel();
                fabaddnew.animate().translationY(btn_initPosY);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            listAdapter.isScrolling(true);

            //what is the bottom item that is visible

            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already? Load more!
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
                if (olimit > totalcount) {

                } else {
                    olimit = olimit + 10;
                    new LoadDataTask().execute(String.valueOf(olimit));
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Background task to load more data from sqlite:

```
class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... olimits) {
        String limits = null;

        loadingMore = true;
        try {
            limits = olimits[0];
            grouplistDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            grouplistDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>>();
            groupdaybooklists = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();
            childdaybook = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();
            databasehandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            loadeddate = new ArrayList<String>();
            String selectquery = "SELECT date,IFNULL(SUM(amountin),0) as amountin,IFNULL(SUM(amountout),0),daybookusertype as amountout FROM daybookdetails GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) DESC LIMIT '" + limits + "'";
            SQLiteDatabase db = databasehandler.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    loadeddate.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    for (String s : loadeddate) {
                        newdate = s;
                    }
                    String[] spiliter = newdate.split("-");
                    String year = spiliter[0];
                    String month = spiliter[1];
                    String dates = spiliter[2];
                    if (month.startsWith("01")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Jan" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Feb" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Mar" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Apr" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "May" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Jun" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Jul" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Aug" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Sep" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Oct" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Nov" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Dec" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    }
                    grouplistDataHeader.add(disorderedlist);
                    groupdaybooklists = databaseHandler.getAllDaywisedaybookdetails(newdate);



                } while (cursor.moveToNext());


                /*for (int j = 0; j < groupdaybooklists.size(); j++) {

                }
                */
            }


            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       // listAdapter.setVTransactionList(grouplistDataHeader);

        for(int j = 0 ;j<daybooklists.size();j++){
            String name = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getName();
            String desc = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getDescription();
            String type = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getType();
            String usertype = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getUsertype();
            String amtin = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getAmountin();
            String amtout = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getAmountout();
            String extamt = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getExtraamt();
            String mobno = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getMobileno();
            String datess = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getSdate();
            String time = groupdaybooklists.get(j).getCtime();
            childdaybook.add(new Daybooklist(name, desc, type, usertype, amtin, amtout, extamt, mobno, datess, time));

        }
        for(int i = 0;i<grouplistDataHeader.size();i++){
            grouplistDataChild.put(grouplistDataHeader.get(i), childdaybook);
        }


        listAdapter.setTransactionList(grouplistDataHeader, grouplistDataChild);

        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            expListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
        loadingMore = false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // Notify the loading more operation has finished
        loadingMore = false;
    }
}
```

I am not getting the next set of datas properly can anyone tell me whether is it the correct way of loading data's from sqlite or is there any better approach to load the data's.

Comment: Pls try with pagging

Comment: Try to notify your adapter that data set is changed.

Comment: @RickyPatel can u tell me what is pagging

Comment: @avinash i have already notified the adapter but it is not working

Comment: @RameshR : Here is the link that may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/32559048/1920735

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996574/pagination-in-listview @RameshR

Answer (score 1):

User **android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout** refer this link [Implementing Swipe to Refresh](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/)

Comment: @ i want to scroll the list from bottom and not from top

Comment: So you can swipe both from top and bottom and supports API 9+. refer this link [OrangeGangsters SwipyRefreshLayout](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to migrate your code to use a RecycleView instead, not only this will make your life much much easier, but also you will have improvements on performance on your app since RecyclerViews have a better memory management implementation.
You can even check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview) how to detect if you need to load more items

Comment: this does not provide the answer to the question. if you suggests recyclerview then post some code relevant to answer