# i get allways this errors when i execute web service application, can you help me please?

Tags: android

```
02-21 14:00:32.442: W/WindowManager(88): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
02-21 14:00:32.621: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(88): setKernelCountSet(10004, 1) failed with errno -2
02-21 14:00:34.962: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(88): setKernelCountSet(10061, 0) failed with errno -2
02-21 14:00:38.403: D/AndroidRuntime(583): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-21 14:00:38.403: D/AndroidRuntime(583): CheckJNI is ON
02-21 14:00:40.521: D/AndroidRuntime(583): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-21 14:00:40.592: D/AndroidRuntime(583): Shutting down VM
02-21 14:00:40.611: I/AndroidRuntime(583): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-21 14:00:40.621: D/dalvikvm(583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 78% free 462K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-21 14:00:40.621: D/jdwp(583): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-21 14:00:40.621: D/dalvikvm(583): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-21 14:00:41.421: D/AndroidRuntime(596): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-21 14:00:41.421: D/AndroidRuntime(596): CheckJNI is ON
02-21 14:00:42.471: D/AndroidRuntime(596): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-21 14:00:42.521: I/ActivityManager(88): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.pfe/.SoappActivity} from pid 596
02-21 14:00:42.531: W/WindowManager(88): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
02-21 14:00:42.611: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(88): setKernelCountSet(10061, 1) failed with errno -2
02-21 14:00:43.221: W/System.err(536):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
02-21 14:00:42.661: I/AndroidRuntime(596): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-21 14:00:42.661: D/dalvikvm(596): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 1ms+3ms
02-21 14:00:42.661: D/jdwp(596): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-21 14:00:42.671: D/dalvikvm(596): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-21 14:00:43.021: W/System.err(536): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-21 14:00:43.021: W/System.err(536):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
02-21 14:00:43.071: W/System.err(536):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-21 14:00:43.071: W/System.err(536):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-21 14:00:43.081: W/System.err(536):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-21 14:00:43.081: W/System.err(536):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
02-21 14:00:43.081: W/System.err(536):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-21 14:00:43.127: W/System.err(536):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
02-21 14:00:43.127: W/System.err(536):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
02-21 14:00:43.131: W/System.err(536):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-21 14:00:43.332: W/System.err(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 14:01:30.961: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_CONCURRENT freed 231K, 4% free 10112K/10503K, paused 23ms+23ms
02-21 14:04:36.751: D/gralloc_goldfish(640): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-21 14:05:40.481: D/AndroidRuntime(640): Shutting down VM
02-21 14:05:40.481: W/dalvikvm(640): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.pfe.MonService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2262)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at com.pfe.MonService.onCreate(MonService.java:58)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2252)
02-21 14:05:40.571: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to execute network call on main (UI) thread. This is not acceptable, because UI should be responsive and network calls are long in most cases. What you need is to run your code on the other thread using Thread class or [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Also, you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask/4538370#4538370) question for some details.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you do? What errors do you get? You can create a separate question for your new version.