# Java Eclipse(android) couldn't insert data to mongodb database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mongodb

Sorry up front, I'm a newbie in mongodb connection code I try to insert database from eclipse (android) to mongodb but nothin happen in my database

When I check in mongo.exe
with "show dbs"
local 0.03125GB
testdb <>

Note: sorry I can't post the image because required reputation.
update problem (13 November 2013)

```
    package com.example.cobanih;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

public class MongoConnection extends Activity{

    /*static final String domain = "localhost";  
    static final int port = 27107;
    static final String database = "test";*/
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LongOperation MyTask= new LongOperation();
        MyTask.execute();
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            insert();
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           // txt.setText(result);
            // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
            // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }

    public boolean insert(){
        System.out.println("check");
        try {
            System.out.println("check2");
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
            System.out.println("check3");
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testdb");

            DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");

            /**** Insert ****/
            // create a document to store key and value
            BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
            document.put("name", "donny");
            document.put("age", 30);
            document.put("createdDate", new Date());
            table.insert(document);

            /**** Find and display ****/
            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            searchQuery.put("name","donny");

            DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }

            mongoClient.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
11-12 13:05:50.822: I/System.out(6069): check
11-12 13:05:50.822: I/System.out(6069): check2
11-12 13:05:54.262: I/dalvikvm(6069): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean, referenced from method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>
11-12 13:05:54.262: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5446: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getRuntimeMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean;
11-12 13:05:54.272: D/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0071
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069): null
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069): java.net.SocketException
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.net.NetworkInterface.rethrowAsSocketException(NetworkInterface.java:224)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:190)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.net.NetworkInterface.getByName(NetworkInterface.java:118)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfacesList(NetworkInterface.java:283)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:274)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:357)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:226)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.<clinit>(DBTCPConnector.java:32)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:193)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:138)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:126)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:115)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection.insert(MongoConnection.java:59)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:37)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:1)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:175)
11-12 13:05:54.462: W/org.bson.ObjectId(6069):  ... 19 more
11-12 13:05:55.122: I/dalvikvm(6069): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.<init>
11-12 13:05:55.142: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5445: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
11-12 13:05:55.142: D/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
11-12 13:05:55.242: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 198K, 10% free 2974K/3292K, paused 72ms+78ms, total 214ms
11-12 13:05:55.262: E/dalvikvm(6069): Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.createObjectName
11-12 13:05:55.262: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 866 (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;) in Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
11-12 13:05:55.262: D/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
11-12 13:05:55.272: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 863 (Ljavax/management/MalformedObjectNameException;)
11-12 13:05:55.272: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x6
11-12 13:05:55.282: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;.createObjectName (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/management/ObjectName;
11-12 13:05:55.282: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0006
11-12 13:05:55.282: W/dalvikvm(6069): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;.createObjectName (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/management/ObjectName;
11-12 13:05:55.282: W/dalvikvm(6069): Verifier rejected class Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
11-12 13:05:55.602: I/System.out(6069): check3
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069): Exception executing isMaster command on localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069): java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:548)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize(Mongo.java:620)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:254)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection.insert(MongoConnection.java:71)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:37)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:1)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-12 13:05:55.852: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069): Exception executing isMaster command on localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069): java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:548)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:527)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:174)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection.insert(MongoConnection.java:71)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:37)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:1)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-12 13:05:56.022: W/com.mongodb.tcp(6069):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069): emptying DBPortPool to localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069): java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:84)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:79)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection.insert(MongoConnection.java:71)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:37)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:1)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-12 13:05:56.123: W/com.mongodb(6069):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-12 13:05:56.332: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 221K, 11% free 3144K/3532K, paused 75ms+73ms, total 198ms
11-12 13:05:56.492: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 7% free 3531K/3772K, paused 73ms+6ms, total 112ms
11-12 13:05:56.492: D/dalvikvm(6069): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
11-12 13:05:56.732: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 6% free 3935K/4160K, paused 72ms+73ms, total 189ms
11-12 13:05:56.912: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 5% free 4358K/4568K, paused 73ms+5ms, total 120ms
11-12 13:05:56.912: D/dalvikvm(6069): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
11-12 13:05:57.102: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7K, 5% free 4901K/5108K, paused 72ms+5ms, total 120ms
11-12 13:05:57.102: D/dalvikvm(6069): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
11-12 13:05:57.362: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 10K, 4% free 5638K/5832K, paused 72ms+5ms, total 121ms
11-12 13:05:57.362: D/dalvikvm(6069): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
11-12 13:05:57.752: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13K, 3% free 6621K/6816K, paused 74ms+75ms, total 205ms
11-12 13:05:58.232: D/dalvikvm(6069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 18K, 2% free 7957K/8116K, paused 74ms+79ms, total 213ms
11-12 13:05:58.232: D/dalvikvm(6069): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
11-12 13:05:58.792: W/System.err(6069): com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't say something
11-12 13:05:58.804: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:194)
11-12 13:05:58.812: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
11-12 13:05:58.812: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
11-12 13:05:58.823: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
11-12 13:05:58.832: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
11-12 13:05:58.842: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
11-12 13:05:58.852: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
11-12 13:05:58.852: W/System.err(6069):     at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection.insert(MongoConnection.java:71)
11-12 13:05:58.862: W/System.err(6069):     at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:37)
11-12 13:05:58.872: W/System.err(6069):     at com.example.cobanih.MongoConnection$LongOperation.doInBackground(MongoConnection.java:1)
11-12 13:05:58.882: W/System.err(6069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-12 13:05:58.892: W/System.err(6069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-12 13:05:58.902: W/System.err(6069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-12 13:05:58.902: W/System.err(6069):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-12 13:05:58.922: W/System.err(6069):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-12 13:05:58.922: W/System.err(6069):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-12 13:05:58.942: W/System.err(6069): Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-12 13:05:58.952: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
11-12 13:05:58.962: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
11-12 13:05:58.962: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:84)
11-12 13:05:58.982: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:79)
11-12 13:05:58.982: W/System.err(6069):     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
11-12 13:05:58.982: W/System.err(6069):     ... 15 more
```

What's wrong with this there's no error when I'm debugging..
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: 3 months late but never mind.. 6th line for the bottom it says that you do not have access to the database. Be sure it's running and have access. Also you connect to the localhost which is not accessible over the network (e.g. your phone).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are accessing the web from the main thread which is forbidden in Android (throws exception). The reason for that is that web communications are usually time consuming and might block the user for too long a time hanging the application.

You should use either the Android specific [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class or ordinary [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for web-related communications, also for Database communications, but in your case the latter comprises of the first.

PS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) is a thread of SO that illustrates an easy example of how you use AsyncTask. You should usually define the logic to be executed after the call is executed as callback in the `onPostExecute` method, very rearely you can also [wait for the background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997547/android-wait-asynctask-to-finish/9997729#9997729) to finish (not advisable at all).

NOTE: The application runs either in emulator or oni real device, but for both they need network calls to access your desktop machine.

Comment: what do you mean about that i'm accessing the web from the main thread? and then, how can i insert to mongodb database with async task?

Comment: @DonnyAgusto 1) `MongoClient("localhost",27017)` creates web client, thus accessing the web. 2) you should move the call to `insert()` method in the `doInBackground` method of async task in order to have it not on the main thread (to see how see the link immediately after PS in my answer).

Comment: i've tried use asynctask but still i can't insert collection (look at the updated question)