# Thread wait until a set of async tasks are finished

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask, synchronization

I have a set of HTTP reqeuests that each response adds an entry to ArrayList. Later I use that list to make some checks.
How can I make the program wait until all the requests are done and the list is filled before continuing to checks?

---

**EDIT**

code sample:

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{

    List<Integer> responses;

    @Override
    protected synchronized Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        responses= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for( int i=0; i<10; i++ ){
            restAPI.getNextInt( // SEND HTTP REQUEST
                    new Response.OnSuccess() { // ON SUCCESS CALLBACK
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Integer i) {
                            responses.add(i);
                        }}, 
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }});
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

And in my main thread:

```
BackgroundTask bt = new BackGroundTask();
bt.execute();
bt.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // THIS DOESN'T WAIT
if( bt.responses.contains(10) ){
 ...
}
```

I didn't provided code before because I'm looking for the general solution not a specific for me

---

**EDIT 2**

Here is my second try that it didn't work. I put everything in the main thread.

```
final Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(-params.size()+1);
final List<Integer> responses = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
for( final Param p : params ){
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void start(){
            restAPI.nextInt(p, // SEND HTTP REQUEST
                    new Response.OnSuccess() { // ON SUCCESS CALLBACK
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Integer i) {
                            System.out.print("aaaaa");
                            sema.release();
                            responses.add(i);
                        }}, 
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            sema.release();
                    }});
        }
    }.start();
}
try {
    sema.acquire();
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
if( responses.contains(10) )  
...
```

Now what happens is that everything blocks/stops in `sema.acquire()` and aaaaa never prints. If I remove `sema.acquire()` then aaaaa prints.
The whole code is in a `protected void onPostExecute(Void result)` of an `AsyncTask` if this matters ...

Comment: are you running each HTTP request in a separate thread?

Comment: use one AsyncTask ...

Comment: @markg No, I have a for loop to send all requests on the same thread in an AsyncTask

Comment: Then I guess i don't understand how you can not know if all the requests are done or not

Comment: instead `for(;;) { new AsyncTask().execute() }` do `new AsyncTask(){ doInBack() { for (;;) {}}}.execute()`

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997547/android-wait-asynctask-to-finish

Comment: Do you know about RxJava and Retrofit?

Comment: @ Kevin Yes I though that this is what I need but I dont know how to use it. Can you please provide some code?

Comment: @Selvin this is what I do ...

Comment: @markg I've checked this question but it didn't help

Comment: Actually it is you who should provide the code that you are trying, not Selvin...

Comment: *No, I have a for loop to send all requests on the same thread in an AsyncTask* ... then why in the question is *wait 'till set of async tasks are finished* ? ... it doesn't make sens at all ...

Comment: @SJuan76 I was looking for a general solution. In any case I updated my question

Comment: @Selvin you are right it doesn't make any sense. I used AsycTask because I thought that it would do what I wanted to.

Comment: ok, first check if your `restAPI` doesn't have sync methods ... if not ... then you could just call restAPI.getNextInt inside onResponse until you done all without AsyncTask at all ...

Comment: restAPI didn't had any synchronized methods ... but I changed it. I'm not sure how your suggestion will make the main thread stops until everything finish...

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with semaphores? Basically a semaphore has a number associated with it. Lets say you have five http requests to make. You will initialize the semaphore's number to -4. From your main thread that needs to wait for the list to be filled, call the acquire method on the semaphore. This will cause the thread to block (wait) until the semaphore's number has a value of 1. In each of your async threads, call "release" on the semaphore after the async thread is done adding its entry to the list. Each time you call release on the semaphore, the semaphore's number is incremented by 1. Thus when all of the async threads are finished, the semaphore will have a value of 1, allowing the main thread to continue executing. For future reference, calling acquire on the semaphore will decrement the value back to zero.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(-4);

for each http request that needs to be made:
  spawn a separate thread to execute this function {
     do http request and insert entry into list
     sema.release();
  }

sema.acquire(); // block main thread until http requests are done
doStuff(); //The list is already filled, do whatever you need to do.
```

Comment: When I put a Semaphore(0) or below, everything stop/block. I don't not what might be at fault. I have a thread for every HTTP request ...

Comment: Can you place a print statement before you call sema.release(); and make sure that the release is being executed at all? You should also put one before sema.acquire() to ensure that is where it is blocked.

Comment: Based on the fact that it happens when only when you use 0 or below, it seems that release isn't being called.

Comment: I added a print inside the response callback. It didn't print.  
I removed sema.acquire from my main thread and it prints ...  
I don't know why.  
I use seperate threads to send requests.  
I also want to mention that the whole code is inside  `onPostExecute()` of an AsyncTask. If this matters