# AsyncTask onCancelled(Object) never invoked after asyncTask.cancel(true);

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

As the documentation says the `onCancelled(Object)` should be invoked after:

**cancel(boolean) is invoked and doInBackground(Object[]) has finished.**

In my `AsyncTask` i invoked `this.cancel(true);` but the `onCancelled(Object)` method is never called.

Only relevant code is posted here.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
 AsyncTask.Status asyncTaskStatus = new GetHtmlDocument(urlString).execute().getStatus();
```

**AsyncTask**:

```
private class GetHtmlDocument extends AsyncTask<String,Void,HtmlPage>
    {
        private String url;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param url Url to parse from in the web.
         */
        public GetHtmlDocument(String url)
        {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            Log.d(MainActivity.ASYNC_TASK_TAG, "onPreExecute() called");
        }

        @Override
        protected HtmlPage doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
            Log.d(MainActivity.ASYNC_TASK_TAG, "doInBackground() called");

            if (this.isCancelled())
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {


                HtmlPage htmlPage = new HtmlPage(getParsedDocument(this.url));

                return htmlPage;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground().
         * The specified result is the value returned by doInBackground().
         * This method won't be invoked if the asynchronous task was cancelled.
         *
         * @param htmlPage
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HtmlPage htmlPage)
        {
            Log.d(MainActivity.ASYNC_TASK_TAG, "onPostExecute() called");

            if (htmlPage.getHtmlDocument() != null)
            {
                this.cancel(true);
            }

            setHtmlPage(htmlPage);
        }

        /**
         * A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
         * Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true.
         * After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns.
         * To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)
         *
         * @param htmlPage
         *
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(HtmlPage htmlPage)
        {
            Log.d(MainActivity.ASYNC_TASK_TAG, "onCancelled() called");
        }


    }
```

I debugged the app and I know for sure that `this.cancel(true);` is called in the `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply because you are calling the `this.cancel(true)` after the AsyncTask done its job!

Means, you can cancel the AsyncTask, while it is doing its job in `doInBackground`, and after its status is "finished"

from Docs,

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean)`.
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` to
>   return true. After invoking this method, `onCancelled(Object)`, instead
>   of `onPostExecute(Object)` will be invoked after
>   `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])`, if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

So its clear that the `onCancelled` method is meant to be called while the AsyncTask is performing task before `doInBackground` is completed, and `onCancelled(Object)` is clearly meant to be invoked "**INSTEAD**" of `onPostExecute` on an event of cancelling. the `cancel(true)`method is meant to "interrupt" the operation of AsyncTask.

And, i would like to know why you want to cancel the task? you could simply check whether the result is null and perform the onPostExecute only if its not null, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HtmlPage htmlPage)
{
    if (htmlPage.getHtmlDocument() != null){
       Log.d(MainActivity.ASYNC_TASK_TAG, "onPostExecute() called");
       setHtmlPage(htmlPage);
    }
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HtmlPage htmlPage)
{
    Log.d(MainActivity.ASYNC_TASK_TAG, "onPostExecute() called");
    if (htmlPage.getHtmlDocument() != null){
       return;
    }

    setHtmlPage(htmlPage);
}
```

Comment: Let me get this strait. When `onPostExecute()` is called the `AsyncTask` will be terminated naturally?

Comment: No.

From Doc : `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. 

Aftr excutn of `onPostExecute`, AsyncTask Terminates naturally. But you hv control over `onPostExecute` to exit like return. The `cancel(true)` is provided to give you/user a control of the Background execution of asynctask, like if it takes too much time, we need to cancel it. cancel(true) method provides an opportunity to cancel the AsyncTask while its performing its Background operation.

And, if you can explain why you want to cancel the Task in `onPostExecute`, I can explain more

Comment: @God please accept my answer if that addresses your issue. Thanks

Comment: First of all thank you. Second - I'm using `Jsoup` to parse a `HTML` page in `doInBackground()` method. The problem is the parsing not always succeeds and thus the htmlPage object is null. I want to know when `doInBackground()` successfully parsed the page and then assign that value in the `onPostExecute()` to a global variable of `HtmlPage` and that the `doInBackground()` will not be called again so it could not change the value of the global `HtmlPage` to null again.

Comment: it could be done in the onPostExecute by checking if the HtmlPage is null and setting a global variable accordingly. no need to do the cancel.

and, if you are performing a loop operation in doinbackground, and you need to stop it if in any iteration the HtmlPage is null, then just check `if(HtmlPage == null)` on each iteration and `return HtmlPage;` if its true.

cancel is meant to give external interruption. you have other measures to end the operations internally :-)

Comment: Ok. I do check in `onPostExecute()` if htmlPage is null but i want to completely kill/destroy/terminate all the`AsyncTask` operation after i got what i wanted which is a not null htmlPage. How do i do that? Because when i debug with step by step I see it always goes back to `doInBackgroudn()` method.

Comment: never mind the cursor goes back. it traverses through all way back which it travelled.

after onPostExecute, AsyncTask will be terminated.

Comment: Ah nice. I finally getting to understand that class. But I have another question if you mind. If after `onPostExecute()` the `AsyncTask` is terminated and the `Parsing` failed(null) , i need to call the `AsyncTask` execute method again. That means i need to run a `Loop` on the `onCreate()` thread that checks to see the status of the `AsyncTask`. How do i accomplish that check?

Comment: That's a real bad idea :-) It may end in an endless loop, crashing the app :-)

Better way is to notify user that the parsing failed and to refresh, and in refresh, make call the Asynctask execute again.

Comment: So to call `execute()` every time I get null? But how would i know the `AsyncTask` has finished? check the status? That's means looping on the status till i get `finish()` status. Is that a better idea? Thanks for all the time you putting into me man.