# My callback method is never called using an interface

Tags: android, multithreading, interface, callback, ui-thread

I'm trying to implement a `callback` method to be called whenever a `Thread` is is done It's work.
I'm using the `interface` approach and not the `Handler` approach.

I have a main `UI` `Thread` which is the `onCreate(Bundle)` method and a `Thread` i call from within the `onCreate(Bundle)` method.

(Only relevant code posted).

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback
{
    public static GetDataFromTheWebThread getDataFromTheWebThread;
    private GetDataFromTheWebEventNotifier eventNotifier;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.eventNotifier = new GetDataFromTheWebEventNotifier(MainActivity.this);

        // The thread that will search the web for data
        this.getDataFromTheWebThread = new GetDataFromTheWebThread();
        getDataFromTheWebThread.start();
     }

        @Override
        public void finishParsing() // The callback method that never called
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Callback Method Called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Callback:", "Callback Method Called");
        }
}
```

**GetDataFromTheWebEventNotifier.java**:

```
public class GetDataFromTheWebEventNotifier
{
    private GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback callbackInterface;

    public GetDataFromTheWebEventNotifier(GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback callbackInterface)
    {
        this.callbackInterface = callbackInterface;
    }

    public void onEvent()
    {
            this.callbackInterface.finishParsing();
    }
}
```

**GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback.java**:

```
public interface GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback
{
    void finishParsing(); // The method i wish to invoke when certain event will happen
}
```

**GetDataFromTheWebThread.java**:

```
public class GetDataFromTheWebThread extends Thread
{
    public static boolean isFinished = false; // False - the thread is still running. True - the thread is dead

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        GetDataFromTheWebThread.isFinished = false;
        try
        {
            // Some internet computations...
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataFromTheWebThread.isFinished = true;
    }
}
```

So what's wrong with my `callback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your ThreadClass, have a constructor with the callback :

```
public class GetDataFromTheWebThread extends Thread {
    public static boolean isFinished = false; // False - the thread is still running. True - the thread is dead
    private GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback mCallback;

    public GetDataFromTheWebThread(GetDataFromTheWebThreadCallback c) {
      mCallback = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      GetDataFromTheWebThread.isFinished = false;
      try {
        // Some internet computations...
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      GetDataFromTheWebThread.isFinished = true;
      if (mCallback !- null) {
        mCallback.finishParsing();
      }
    }
}
```

As for your Activity, simply pass the callback when creating your Thread :

```
this.getDataFromTheWebThread = new GetDataFromTheWebThread(this);
```

As well as :

```
    @Override
    public void finishParsing()  {
      // You know that this function is called from a background Thread.
      // Therefore from here, run what you have to do on the UI Thread
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Callback Method Called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.d("Callback:", "Callback Method Called");
        }});

    }
```

Comment: But that way It's not really a `callback`. I want to check if `GetDataFromTheWebThread.isFinished = true;` on the `onEvent()` method and not to call the `callback` when i know i `Thread` has done. Oh and it give `RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: @God What do you mean it's not really a callback? A callback is meant to call a special piece of code once an event occurs, such as the thread finishes in your case.

Comment: Well, It's still generates a `RunTimeException`

Comment: as for the exception, see my Edit (runOnUIThread()) which will force the callback call to be run from the UIThread, thus prevent your RunTimeException

Comment: Or i could just  use `Looper.prepare();` at the start of `run()` method!

Comment: And `runOnUiThread` is not recognizable in my `Thread` `run()` scoop. So correct you'r answer to either `Looper.prepare()` or to pass the `Avtivity` as a parameter to the `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

You never call `onEvent()`. Is your notifier supposed to be watching the `isFinished` variable or something?

Comment: Because i want to call `onEvent()` if the `Thread` is finished AKA `GetDataFromTheWebThread.isFinished = true;`

Comment: `Is your notifier supposed to be watching the isFinished variable or something?` I don't know. I just want him to call `onEvent()` which will call the `callback` method whenever the `Thread` is "dead".

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't call onEvent(). And check [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Already tried. Didn't went well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520737/asynctask-onpostexecute-is-never-called-w-art-suspending-all-threads-took. And where to cal `onEvent()`?