# Xml download from server.Timeout not working

Tags: android, timeout, urlconnection

I am trying to download some xml files through this code.
Everything works fine when network is available.I have already handled the issue when network is not at all there. But the issue m facing right now is that ,when network is slow ,the download doesnt timeout.

Time out is not at all working ,I think.How to make it work?

```
            URL mUrl = new URL(url[i]);
            URLConnection conexion = mUrl.openConnection();
            response[i] = new DownloadResponse();
            response[i].setSuccessful(false);
            conexion.connect();
            conexion.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            ByteArrayOutputStream outBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (outputFile != null) { // one output file specified in constructor
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        outputFile));
            } else if (outputFiles != null) { // an array of output files specified
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        outputFiles[i]));
            } else {// no output file specified
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(outBytes);
            }
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(mUrl.openStream());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            response[i].setSuccessful(true);
            response[i].count = i;
            response[i].setResponseText(outBytes.toString());
            if (total < 32 && outBytes.toString().indexOf("Invalid") < -1){
                response[i].setSuccessful(false);
            }

            output.close();
            input.close();
            publishProgress(response[i]);
```

Comment: Does this help you? :http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089528/1405983

Comment: @Prince No, It checks for internet connection.I want to check slow internet.Want to cancel the download if it is taking long

Comment: Okey! Just read this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/11942965/1405983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in onclick whendownload button
define globally in class `boolean b = true;`

```
count_Timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                b = false;
                pd.dismiss();
                dialog.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AppSetting.this);
                builder1.setTitle("appname");
                builder1.setMessage("You can't Continue because internet is Very slow.");
                builder1.setNeutralButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                            }
                        });
                builder1.show();

            }
        };
```

on beginning of download task

```
count_Timer.start();
```

on last line of doinbackground

```
count_Timer.cancel();
```

and on postexecute method

```
if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();

            if (b) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                simplealert(result.replace("\"", ""));

            } else {

            }
```