# Execute Progress bar between two activities android

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have two activities on my android application & at the second one, it takes a while to load the data, I want to use the *Progress bar* to make the user feel there is an action happening, but I don't know how to set the code of the progress bar to run while a block of code executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to show `ProgressDialog` either before switching to the new activity, or just after new activity is shown, but data is still loading.
You can check it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Comment: I suggest to look at this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask
 
Besides of just showing ProgressDialog, it is a good idea to push loading from Main Thread to AsyncTask. Progress dialog will be shown before task will be completed and data loaded.

Comment: Even better example - http://www.androidsnippets.com/grab-a-url-source-with-progressdialog-and-asynctask , that's just what you need. I don't like the codestyle, however, it is up to you :)

Comment: thanks so much for your help ,, i read the artical and also the Application is Running now :)