# AsyncTask with Dialog and method call?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below is my code: that works fine but dialog not showing.Dialog should open with ASyncTask starts and dismiss with ends.how is is possible to do?

```
    Public class RootClass
    {
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public List methodA(String a)
    ----
    ----
```

Class childClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RootClass.this,"Please wait", "Message");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ----
    ---
    ---
        List<String> B=methodA(String a);
    -----
    -----

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        return;
    }
}

}</pre>

Comment: have you logged the time difference, maybe the Asynctask is getting over very fast

Comment: 1st possibilty : your doInBackground() has a very small task to do... so the dialog appears and dimiss very quickly(unnoticeable)....
to check this... try commenting dialog.dismiss()

2nd Possibility: u are not calling the asyncTask properly....

Comment: no.. its taking almost 1 and half minute..

Comment: if m not calling asynctask properly , it not go to postexecute , but it goes there and do later process

Comment: @lakhani Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask) can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Your RootClass should extend Activity class

```
 public class RootClass extends Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

in the onCreate method. on the very event when you are going to start the async task write

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RootClass.this,"Please wait", "Message");
```

you cannot update the ui in the doiin backgroung() metho,,

and later onPostExecute(), dialog.dissmiss;.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using - `public ProgressDialog dialog;`

Try using-- `public Dialog process;`

and in Async taks use this code

```
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
progress = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Please wait",
                "Loading..", true);
}
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
if (progress.isShowing()) {
progress.dismiss();
}
```

Hope this helps!