# Show ProgressDialog when loading heavy UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I use `asynctask` quite often however this time it doesn't work!
I have a UI contains a `viewpager` and `fragments`. To populate the view, it takes about 3 secs. Now I want to show the ProgressDialog until it finishes by using `AsyncTask`. But the `ProgressDialog` is not showing!!!!

Anybody can tell me the solution? Thanks

```
onCreate(...){
   setContentView(...)
   new LoadUI(MyActivity.this).execute();
}

public class LoadUI extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context context;

    public LoadUI(Context mContext) {
        this.context = mContext;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        aViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.aPagerDay);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Create ViewPager
        //Create pagerAdapter
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any solution of this issue?

Comment: Just move it to onResum()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the GUI is not ready in `onCreate()`. And nothing will be shown if I try to show `Dialog` in this state. A solution is move the `dialog` to activity `onStart()`:

```
@override
onStart(){
   new LoadUI(MyActivity.this).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out two options:

Either use the `AsyncTask`'s method `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` like that:

```
task.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This will make your main thread wait for the result of the `AsyncTask` at most 1000 milliseconds.

Alternatively you can show a progress dialog in the async task until it finishes. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538370/1108032). Basically a progress dialog is shown while the async task runs and is hidden when it finishes.

You have even third option:" if `Thread` is sufficient for your needs you can just use its `join` method. However, if the task is taking a long while you will still need to show a progress dialog, otherwise you will get an exception because of the main thread being inactive for too long.

Comment: Thanks, but any idea about why progressdialog didn't show up?