# Android ProgressDialog isn't working

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I try to make a ProgressDialog that shows the user the progress of connecting with a Bluetooth device but my progress dialog stays at 0% and the Bluetooth device doesn't connect. When I call the functions in onCreate() it connects but I won't have a ProgressDialog when I do that.

I don't know what to do!

PLEASE HELP!

This is my code

```
public void StartConnection(){
    loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loading.setTitle("Loading connection...");
    loading.setMessage("Loading...");
    loading.setProgressStyle(loading.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    loading.setProgress(0);
    loading.setMax(100);
    loading.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Get device ID
                loading.setProgress(0);
                loading.setMessage("Getting device ID...");
                try {
                    getDeviceId();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't get device ID");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 101: Couldn't get device ID\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(20);

                //Open connection
                loading.setMessage("Opening connection...");
                try{
                    openConnection();
                } catch (IOException ex){
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't open connection");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 102: Couldn't open connection\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(40);

                //Testing connection
                loading.setMessage("Testing connection...");
                if (!mmSocket.isConnected()){
                    ErrorMessage("Test failed!");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 103: Test failed!\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(60);

                //Calibrate sensors
                loading.setMessage("Calibrating sensors...");
                try{
                    sendCommand("c");
                }catch (IOException ex){
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't calibrate sensors");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 104: Couldn't calibrate sensors\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(80);

                //Finish
                loading.setMessage("Finishing...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loading.setProgress(90);

                //Clear
                loading.setMessage("Clearing some stuff...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loading.setProgress(100);

                if (loading.getProgress() == loading.getMax()) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished, connection is established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Edit:
I think this is the problem:

```
03-05 19:34:28.342 3488-3488/com.jules_citronic.racecarcontrol E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.jules_citronic.racecarcontrol/com.jules_citronic.racecarcontrol.Menu}
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.jules_citronic.racecarcontrol/com.jules_citronic.racecarcontrol.Menu}
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3509)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Edit:
I tried to apply the you suggestion but i gives this error:

[AndroidStudio gives an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCAnS.png)

Edit:
Eh, stil doesn't work :(

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJAHC.png)

Here is the whole function:

```
private void StartConnection(){
    loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loading.setTitle("Loading connection...");
    loading.setMessage("Loading...");
    loading.setProgressStyle(loading.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    loading.setProgress(0);
    loading.setMax(100);
    loading.show();

    new Thread( runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Get device ID
                loading.setProgress(0);
                loading.setMessage("Getting device ID...");
                try {
                    getDeviceId();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't get device ID");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 101: Couldn't get device ID\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(20);

                //Open connection
                loading.setMessage("Opening connection...");
                try {
                    openConnection();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't open connection");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 102: Couldn't open connection\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(40);

                //Testing connection
                loading.setMessage("Testing connection...");
                if (!mmSocket.isConnected()) {
                    ErrorMessage("Test failed!");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 103: Test failed!\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(60);

                //Calibrate sensors
                loading.setMessage("Calibrating sensors...");
                try {
                    sendCommand("c");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't calibrate sensors");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 104: Couldn't calibrate sensors\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(80);

                //Finish
                loading.setMessage("Finishing...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loading.setProgress(90);

                //Clear
                loading.setMessage("Clearing some stuff...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loading.setProgress(100);

                if (loading.getProgress() == loading.getMax()) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished, connection is established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    })).start();
}
```

Edit:
Fixed the runOnUiThread:

```
private void StartConnection(){
    loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loading.setTitle("Loading connection...");
    loading.setMessage("Loading...");
    loading.setProgressStyle(loading.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    loading.setProgress(0);
    loading.setMax(100);
    loading.show();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Get device ID
                loading.setProgress(0);
                loading.setMessage("Getting device ID...");
                try {
                    getDeviceId();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't get device ID");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 101: Couldn't get device ID\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(20);

                //Open connection
                loading.setMessage("Opening connection...");
                try {
                    openConnection();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't open connection");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 102: Couldn't open connection\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(40);

                //Testing connection
                loading.setMessage("Testing connection...");
                if (!mmSocket.isConnected()) {
                    ErrorMessage("Test failed!");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 103: Test failed!\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(60);

                //Calibrate sensors
                loading.setMessage("Calibrating sensors...");
                try {
                    sendCommand("c");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ErrorMessage("Couldn't calibrate sensors");
                    ErrorAlert += "Error 104: Couldn't calibrate sensors\n";
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loading.setProgress(80);

                //Finish
                loading.setMessage("Finishing...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loading.setProgress(90);

                //Clear
                loading.setMessage("Clearing some stuff...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loading.setProgress(100);

                if (loading.getProgress() == loading.getMax()) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished, connection is established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

But now the ProgressDialog doesn't appear at all.:( When I click on the button that starts the activity, the screen goes black and freezes, when the Bluetooth connects, it loads the layout. Never showed a ProgressDialog.

Comment: Use runOnUiThread method as mentioned in the link : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11140429/5207572](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11140429/5207572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android itself contains a great API for background processes which need to interact with the main UI thread.[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is the way to go for that, it will save you all the heavy lifting making all threading operations very easy for you (internally uses `Thread`, `Handler`, `Executor`, `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `FutureTask` among others).

Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538370/812598) and you will make it work in few steps.

All you need to know is this main concepts of AsyncTask helper:

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> 1 - **onPreExecute()**, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> 2 - **doInBackground(Params...)**,
>   invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute()
>   finishes executing. This step is used to perform background
>   computation that can take a long time. The parameters of the
>   asynchronous task are passed to this step. The result of the
>   computation must be returned by this step and will be passed back to
>   the last step. This step can also use publishProgress(Progress...) to
>   publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on
>   the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> 3 - **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)**, invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.
>
> 4 - **onPostExecute(Result)**, invoked on the UI thread after
>   the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>   computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Comment: This is a little bit beyond my java skills, can you edit my script?? Thanx ;)

Comment: Sorry @JulesHummelink I cannot do that for you, the reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html is written for dummies. There is even an example called `DownloadFilesTask` where they use the `onProgressUpdate` method to update the progressView as you do with `loading.setProgress(0);`. You should at least try to read and code it, there is no any other way to improve your Java skills. If I write it out for you, you won't make any step forward, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to update ProgressDialog from a new Thread but it was created on UI thread. You can't do that. See your IDE's output logs.
Take a look on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread) to add runOnUiThread method.

It works on OnCreate because the code is executed by UI thread.

Comment: wrap your runnable instance with runOnUiThread like this :

new Thread(
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
// run function
});
).start();

Comment: sorry, delete the semicolon...

the error on Runnable disappear when you add the override function :

    new Thread( runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { // your code } }) ).start();

Comment: Fixed it, but now the ProgressDialog doesn't appear at all.:( When I click on the button that starts the activity, the screen goes black and freezes, when the Bluetooth connects, it loads the layout. Never showed a ProgressDialog.