# Dismissing DialogFragment

Tags: android

I am displaying a `FragmentDialog F`. I would like to dismiss it if the response from server is positive. I use AsyncTask to make a request after user click OK on the `F`. I cannot dismiss a window immediately because I have to wait for response from server.

I see two solutions:

1. Dismiss dialog and display again.
2. Try to hide a `Fragment` using fragment manager by tag.

What is better solution? Is there canonical way to do it?

3. Let's assume the following situation:
   I have a button `B`. If user clicks `B` then send a request to the server. I am going to wait for a response so I show `ProgressDialog P`. When resposne arrived I would like to show `DialogFragment`. I have two doubts:

3a) What if user is very fast:
click `B` -> click `B` -> showProgressDialog P `. 
I mean, user clicked twice very fast. He managed do it because he had done it before ProgressDialog appeared ( He triggered two events).

I am not sure whether a such scenario is possible. If not, please convince me.

3b) I want to commit to `FragmentManager` when AsyncTask is completed to show `FragmenDialog`. But, how to? I don't know state of Activity!

Answer (score 0):

Just dismiss your `FragmentDialog F` as soon as the user hits OK. And then show a [progress dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) for the duration your `AsyncTask` is running.

See this answer to know how to show and dismiss progress dialog : [progressDialog in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538370/3857465)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom DialogFragment class, use that AsyncTask inside of it and on onPostExecute just dismiss it if the results is the desired one.

If you are not using a custom class, just create one to use Async task inside it.